Multilinestrings to Linestring using Python
I have a geodataframe (download link) that contains the geometry of bus lines. It is a Multilinestring. I need to transform the geometry into a single Linestring.
My first idea was to use .explode (GeoPandas).
sel = gpd.read_file(".../sel_overflow.geojson")
exp_sel = sel
exp_sel.explode()

Result:

As you can see, the .explode() splitted the Multilinestring into two Linestrings.
Furthermore, I used shapely linemerge and I got the same Multilinestring back.
from shapely.ops import linemerge

geometry = sel.loc[0, 'geometry']
shapely_object = geometry  
line = linemerge(shapely_object)
gdf = gpd.GeoDataFrame(index=[0], crs='epsg:32718', geometry=[line])



If you wish to ask about doing this using PostGIS or R then please do that in a separate question and include a code attempt.

You could brute force it by flattening the line parts with geometry.get_coordinates().
import geopandas as gpd
from shapely.geometry import  LineString

df = gpd.read_file("sel_overflow.geojson")
print(df.head())

df.geometry = df.geometry.apply(lambda geom: LineString(gpd.GeoSeries(geom).get_coordinates()))
print(df.head())

df.to_file("sel_overflow_single.geojson")

Output:
   OBJECTID                                           geometry
0       100  MULTILINESTRING ((265097.514 8665069.813, 2650...
   OBJECTID                                           geometry
0       100  LINESTRING (265097.514 8665069.813, 265046.3 8...

It won't work for something like the following though as a linestring can only have a single start and a single end point:


Thanks for your answer. It works on some geometries, but it can't handle other MultiLineStrings that are similar to the one that you posted.

That's right. Those can't be a converted to a linestring which can only have a single start and a single end point.

You can create points along the line then combine them to recreate each geometry as a LineString.
import geopandas as gpd
from shapely.geometry import LineString

df = gpd.read_file(r"C:\Users\bera\Downloads\sel_overflow.geojson")
ax = df.plot(color="black", linewidth=3, zorder=1, figsize=(10,5))

#print(df.geometry)
#0    MULTILINESTRING ((265097.514 8665069.813, 2650...

#For each row, create interpolated points every d distanc along each geometry 
#  and combine them into a line. I use normalized distances to create a point 
#  every 1/1000 distance along the line.
df["geometry"] = df.apply(lambda x: LineString(
    [x.geometry.line_interpolate_point(distance=d/1000, normalized=True) 
     for d in range(1,1001)]), axis=1)

#print(df.geometry)
#0    LINESTRING (264959.744 8664991.409, 264834.535...

df.plot(ax=ax, color="yellow", linewidth=1, zorder=2)


